# Is there a way to assert that an enum has not changed since the last revision?

Tags: java, svn, netbeans, junit

There exists an enum class that will cause problems downstream if it is changed without also making changes to the downstream project. Unfortunately, this is not easily identified by just searching for usages of the enum. We have had big warning comments in the code saying "Don't change this without also changing (downstream project)", but apparently that wasn't enough: Murphy's Law held firm. I need some other way of preventing other developers (or future me) from breaking things.

My current approach is to create a Unit test that will throw an error whenever the enum is changed. Changing the enum will therefore cause the build to fail which should get the attention of the developer. Included in the failure message will be instructions on how to safely update the enum. Unfortunately I can't see any way of writing this unit test short of copying the entire enum into the test class and then comparing every value from the test enum to the actual enum.

Is there a way that I can avoid duplicating the enum in the test class here? Is there a best practice that you recognize I should be following based on my description?

Comment: what specific changes are you worried about?  changing the ordinal order? Adding new methods?

Comment: Adding rows to the end of the enums is enough to cause problems if it's not communicated. Changing the enum name is actually worse than changing the ordinal order in this case.

Comment: By "adding rows" do you mean defining additional enum constants of that enum type?

Comment: Sounds like whatever is downstream that relies on this behavior needs to have tests that assert the number of "rows" or names of the enum.

Comment: Also, if you were to "compar[e] every value from the test enum to the actual enum", what all would you actually need to compare?  Just names? Or do the enums have data members that you would also need to compare?  And you said that changing the enum name would be *worse* than changing the ordinal order, but does that mean you want to test for matching ordinal order, or not?

Comment: By adding rows I mean defining additional enum constants. I have suggested to the developers in charge of the downstream project that the unit tests belong on their side of the fence (since their project is the one that has problems), but they insist it's something I should be doing. The problem really comes because the downstream project is so tightly coupled to this enum, but I don't think they'll be willing to change that either.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I would just need to test the enum name. Thinking about it, order does not matter, but there is a data member named "id" that I was thinking about when I said the name would be worse than the order. It so happens that the id is equivalent to the order, but that's not required by any project. - edit: other data members of the enum ("description") can be changed without negatively affecting anything.

Comment: Adding additional enum values to an existing enum (at the end, so ordinals do not change) should be safe and not break anything. If it does, my opinion is it's the fault of the _user_, the downstream project, for enum-abuse.  Without a lot more information it's difficult to suggest a course of action, but (again in my opinion) the solution you're looking for in your question is the wrong approach. Adjustments on both enum and consumer may be needed, but you want to end up with a "safe" setup that doesn't break so easily. "Plan for expansion". Maybe this should be a class, not an enum?

Comment: If the developer ignored the comment in the enum, why wouldn't they ignore the same comment in the test?

Comment: @jtahlborn, it's kinda hard to ignore a test failure that breaks the build, as the OP described.  The question presumes a build process that runs the tests and ensures they all pass as part of a standard build.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - i'm not referring to ignoring the build failure.  obviously they have to fix the test.  however, they modified one java class (the original enum) with a big warning on it.  why would modifying a second java class (the unit test) with a big warning in it make a huge difference?

Comment: @jtahlborn, it might not make a difference.  Certainly this approach cannot *prevent* developers from doing the wrong thing.  But there is a difference between "the dev got wrong because he wasn't paying enough attention" and "a one-eyed monkey would have known it was the wrong thing to do".  If devs have to go to monkey territory to do the wrong thing then the problem will not arise with anyone you want to keep.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to verify is the enum member names and maybe their order, then you can create a static method on the enum type that computes a digested form of that information.  Your unit test can then invoke a single method to test whether the enum matches expected form.

For example,

```
enum Test {
    T1;
    static int computeSignature() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (Test t : values) {
            sb.append(t.name()).append(';');
        }

        return sb.toString().hashCode();
    }
}

// ...

private final static int EXPECTED_ENUM_SIG = /* some number */;

@Test
public void testEnumSignature() {
    assertEquals("enum Test has been unexpectedly changed", EXPECTED_ENUM_SIG,
            Test.computeSignature());
}
```

If you decide you don't care about the enum order, then sort the names as part of the signature computation.

Comment: this is a similar idea to what i was thinking, but why not just use the string itself as the signature instead of the hash (seems safer with no real downside)?

Comment: @jtahlborn, one certainly could use the string itself.  That would also be consistent with my answer, and it would be easier to read.  On the other hand, one might not *want* easier to read.  The point seems to be to make changing the enum a big enough hurdle to get developers' attention.  The sweet spot is high enough to justify firing slobs who hack around the barrier instead of implementing the change the right way, but not so high that doing things the right way is hard.

Answer (score 1):

Once an enum class is published it becomes part of the **Public API** and for the most part, should not be changed.  Enum constant names should definitely should not be changed and you probably shouldn't add any new constants either.

This really isn't that much different than changing method signatures on interfaces and should be treated the same way.

Any change is an API breaking change and will affect any downstream programs that link to your enum.

If you really must change your enum then your library should bump up the major version number and include detailed release notes explaining the change and exactly what must be done to make old code compatible.

Unfortunately, the workarounds for enums are not pretty.

Since you can't extend enums if you want to add new enums you can't just extend the old enum class and add a few more constants.

I would recommend extracting an `interface` for the methods in the enum and have your enum class implement the new interface and try to get your downstream software to only use the interface. Then future versions of your code can add new constants with less problems.  But the initial transition to an interface will be painful but hopefully only happen once.

This is covered in some detail in Effective Java 2nd Edition Item 34: "Emulate extensible enums with interfaces"

Comment: I quite agree, but this doesn't answer the question.  Even if the OP switched to interfaces instead of enums, he would (one presumes) be faced with the same problem.

Comment: Yes but it would only happen once instead of every time in the future the enum changes

Comment: that's not clear to me.  You could be right, but much depends on *why* adding enum constants is a particular issue for the downstream project, and on whether that project needs to be able to access and use the new values in the event that any are added.